# Sublime Text Find+Replace adding mystery text

Tags: sublimetext2

When I do a simple Find+Replace All, Sublime Text is inserting extra text beyond what I put in the "Replace With" field. I have no idea where this other text is coming from. In this case, it's adding "\ncircle".

So if I have this text:

```
Hello 1 Hello 2
```

.. and I do this Find+Replace operation:

```
Find What: Hello
Replace With: BLAH
```

.. the output is:

```
BLAH
circle 1 BLAH
circle 2
```

I'm using Sublime Text 2.0.1 under Ubuntu. Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Does the problem persist after [reverting to a freshly installed state](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned: the problem is intermittent and went away this time when I rebooted the system.

Comment: Interesting. If it comes back, I think you should back up your Packages folder, [revert](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html), and start re-building your settings and packages until it (hopefully doesn't) pop up again.

Comment: Find What and Replace With fields can have multiple lines. Probably you had 'BLAH\ncircle' in replace field.

Comment: T--, I bet you're right. Next time it happens, I'll look for this.